# Is Triple Equal To A Valid Operator in C?

Tags: c, operators

I am sitting in a Web Development Workshop and the guy just told that there is a Triple Equal To Operator `===` in C along with others as well. (The Only Language I have read till now).

Just tried this code in Visual Studio 2013 and the compiler is giving me errors that there is a syntax error where I typed the `===`. Here is the source code -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
int i=5;
char ch=5;
if (i === ch)
    printf("The Values Are Equal");
else
    printf("The Values Are Not Equal");


_getch();
}
```

The guy told that such operator is used to compare the value along with the data type of the variable as well. So, am I wrong with my code (Same code written by the guy) or is the guy wrong?

Comment: That sounds like javascript, not C...

Comment: There is no `===` operator in C.

Comment: @P0W - The teacher who is conducting the workshop.

Comment: `===` is not an operator in C. It is used in other languages, such as PHP. In PHP, `===` checks for value and type

Comment: Sounds like whoever is paying for that workshop should ask for a refund. Honest mistakes are fine, but this is one a C programmer -- even an out-of-practice C programmer like myself -- shouldn't have made.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian - True that, he was teaching Javascript and wrote that code, then said that this is valid in C,C++ and almost every other language, that is why I tried that piece of code.

Comment: @PranavJituri probably you should look for another workshop/source of learning

Comment: @P0W &keshlam - Guys, I am attending the workshop at a University which is World Famous and most famous in India so did not hope for this :P . The workshop on Cloud Computing was more than brilliant but this is like this :|

Comment: Triple equal! `a = b = c = d`

Comment: @Swiss - LOL. The code I typed was the same which I have written here man xD.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No.** `=` is used for assignment and `==` is used for equality. There is no `===` operator in C.

Answer (score 1):

Loosely speaking, it does:

```
#define === ==
```

but no, not really.